# Styled with props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-props

I am very new to ReactJS and so not sure if what I am wanting to do is even possible?

I have a styles.ts file that consists of

```
export const Title = styled.h1`
  ${Fonts.H1Bold.Normal};
  color: ${Colors.offWhite};
  font-size: 3.25vw;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin: 0;
`
```

And Film.tsx with..

```
import React from 'react'
import * as S from './style'

import styled from 'styled-components'
import Colors from '#styles/colors'

interface Props {
  title: string
  titleStyle: string
}

const StyledText = styled(S.Title)`
  color: #${props => props.textStyle.substr(8, 3)};
`;

const Film = (props: Props) => {
  return (<div>
    <StyledText baseStyle={S.Title} textStyle={props.titleStyle}>{props.title}</StyledText>
  </div>)
}

export default Film
```

This works, however I would like to use the 'baseStyle' prop in 'StyledText' (as above baseStyle is S.Title).  I have tried..

```
const StyledText = styled((props) => props.baseStyle)`
  ....
'
```

But i am getting errors such as

> Objects are not valid as a React child

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible just a bit messy imo, you can try sth like this:

```
export const Title = styled.h1`
  ...
`
```

```
const StyledText = getStyledText(Title);
...
return (
  <StyledText textStyle={props.titleStyle}>{props.title}</StyledText>
);
```

```
const getStyledText = (Title) => styled(Title)`
  ...
`
```

Comment: I get the following error when doing this which I have seen before when trying something very similar.  I think the issue is the getStyledText() function call.  The component Styled(styled.h1) with the id of "sc-cxNHIi" has been created dynamically.
You may see this warning because you've called styled inside another component.
To resolve this only create new StyledComponents outside of any render method and function component.